# I cant format my 64gb transcend sd card

Tags: partitioning, formatting, sd-card

I partitioned my 64gb sd card into two fat32 and ext4. I am using android mobile and used the ext4 as a way to increase the internal memory of my phone. Suddenly the phone gave error that it could't save into my sd card.I can read the data already there in the card i can copy it to but i cant format it. I tried using sd formatter but it gives error as white protected, but its not and i even removed the readonly protection using diskpart from cmd but it was still the same. I tried to corrupt the mbr but that did not work too. the data is still fine, please tell me how to format it and also i cant delete the ext4 partition also. thank you

Comment: Check if the card's physically write protected. If not and it's failed there's nothing you can do.

Comment: no its not physically write protected ... but how is it that the data in it is still intact. isnt there any other way

Comment: That's how flash can fail. SSDs for example similarly go into read-only mode when their write cycles are exhausted. You can try different Windows/Linux utilities but the chances of recovery are nil in case of hardware failure.

Comment: I spoke with the transcend outlet they agreed to exchange it but the problem is there is sensitive data in it and i cant delete it, so I am a bit worried. I did not know that write cycles got exhausted thank you for the info.